# fibers of $\sin$ are countable

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that:

> Let $\sin: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be the complex sinus function given by $\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$. Then for any $y \in \mathbb{C}$ the set $\{x \in \mathbb{C}: sin(x)=y \}$ is countable.

My ideas: We did not much cover than the definition of $\sin$ and the complex exponential function $\exp$, Euler's formula. I do not really see how to approach to this. Can you give me some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inverse the relation $\sin(x) =y$. Start with $e^{ix}-e^{-ix} = 2iy.$ Multiply by $e^{ix}$ to get $$e^{2ix}-2iye^{ix}-1=0.$$ Set $X=e^{ix}$ to get the equation $$X^2-2iyX-1=0.$$ Hence you get $$X = \frac{2iy \pm \sqrt{4-4y^2}}{2} = iy \pm\sqrt{1-y^2}.$$ Now because $X=e^{ix}$ you finally get $$x = -i \ln\left( iy \pm\sqrt{1-y^2}\right)+2k\pi,$$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}.$ This is clearly countable.

Answer (score 1):

Uncountable sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$ have accumulation points.

Suppose that $S = \{x\in \mathbb{C}\mid \sin x = y\}$ is uncountable, then $S$ has an accumulation point. By the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#An_improvement), $\sin = y$ everywhere, which contradicts the definition of $\sin$.

Hence $\{x\in \mathbb{C}\mid \sin x = y\}$ is countable.

Comment: It's very nice proof, but it uses to advanced techniques. I can only use the very basic as mentioned in the first post.

Comment: @bjn Are you allowed to use differentiation and holomorphy?

Comment: Yes, but only the very basic.

Comment: The proof [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem#An_improvement) only requires basic differentiation.